# creation of a button in RTC GUI

Tags: plugins, eclipse-plugin, snapshot, rational-team-concert

When I create a snapshot in rtc I would like this to be able to be verified before saving it. So I would like to include a "verify" button in the GUI so that I can verify some characteristics of the snapshot such as whether the snapshot is scoped to the project or that it meets a particular naming convention.
How can I do this?
Do I need to create a plugin to do this? Do you have any suggestion to make my job easier?

i would like to do this for RTC version 6.0.6, what kind of sdk should i install? client side?
thanks in advance